# Problem using Next-Auth with Credentials Provider for authenticating on existing system

Tags: javascript, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I am using Next-Auth Credentials provider to authenticate using our existing API.
When I follow the directions on https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks
like this:

```
callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token.accessToken = user.jwt
            }

            return token
        },
        async session({ session, token, user }) {
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken
            return session
        }
    }
```

the resulting session object from useSession() looks like this:

```
{
  expires: "2022-03-22T18:29:02.799Z",
  user: {email: 'john@nextIsGreat.com'}
}
```

I can't use that as it does not have the token available.

So I was able to make up my own working solution, but it is kind of strange because of the way things are grouped together. Here is what I am doing now, that I am trying to figure out how to do better. I use comments to point out the problem areas:

[...nextauth].js:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import axios from 'axios'

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            name: 'Email and Password',
            credentials: {
                username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text', placeholder: 'jsmith' },
                password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' }
            },
            authorize: async (credentials) => {
                const url = process.env.API_URL + '/authenticate'
                const result = await axios.post(url, {
                    username: credentials.username,
                    password: credentials.password
                })

                const user = result.data

                console.log(user)
                //It logs this:
                /*
                  {
                    jwt: 'eyJhbasU1OTJ9.NQ356H4Odya62KmN...', //<---***This is the token i pass in to all of my API calls****
                    user: {
                            userId: 207,
                            email: 'john@nextIsGreat.com',
                            firstName: 'John',
                            lastName: 'Doe',
                            roleId: 1,
                    }
                 }
               */

                if (user) {
                    return Promise.resolve(user)
                } else {
                    return Promise.resolve(null)                
                }
            }
        })
    ],

    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                if (user.jwt) {
                    token = { accessToken: user.jwt, restOfUser: user.user }
                }
            }

            return token
        },
        async session(seshProps) {
            return seshProps
        }
    }
})
```

Home.js:

```
export const Home = () => {

    const { data: session } = useSession()
    
    console.log(session)
    //LOGS THIS --->
      /*
      {
        "session": { "user":{}, "expires":"2022-03-22T17:06:26.937Z"},
        "token":{
                "accessToken":"eyJ...",
                "iat":1645376785,
                "exp":1647968785,
                "jti":"41636a35-7b9a-42fd-8ded-d3dfgh123455a"
                "restOfUser": {
                    "userId":207,
                    "email":"john@nextIsGreat.com",
                    "firstName":"John",
                    "lastName":"Doe",
                    "roleId":1
                }
        }
      {
     */

    const getPosts=()=> {
       const url = 'localhost:4000/posts'
       const {data} = axios.get(url, {
          Authorization: session.token.accessToken   <--**This is the way I am calling my API
       })
       console.log(data)
    }
    
    return (
        <div onClick={getPosts}>
            Hello, {session.token.restOfUser.firstName}
/* I have to access it like this now, which seems wrong ***** */
    
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: _"trying to figure out how to do better"_ - what exactly do you mean by that? Aren't you able to retrieve the token from `useSession`?

Comment: by better I mean I would rather not have to access the user via session.token.restOfUser.firstName. it's hacky

Answer (score 1):

Cheers for creating your own solution but you do not need it. NextAuth `CredentialsProvider` handles it already by setting your [NextAuth session configuration](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#session) to `session: {strategy: "jwt", ... }`.

You can also remove your callbacks for `jwt()` and `session()` and remove your owned generated JWT access token. As you do not need it, this way you can authenticate your existing system.

And at your `CredentialsProvider({authorize(){}}` authorize method. If you had directly connected to the user database, you can directly look up the user credential without doing a post request since it is already considered a server-side function.